# Don't match dot in beginning of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have one path in form of string like this `Folder1/File.png`
But in this string sometimes if file is hidden or folder is hidden I don't want it to be matched by my regex.

```
regex = %r{([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*)\/[^.]+$}

input_path = "Folder_1/.file" # This shouldn't be matched.
input_path = "Folder/file.png" # This should be matched.
```

But my regex works for first input but its not even matching second one.

Comment: How come the regex works for the first input if the regex pattern clearly requires no dots after the last `/` up to the line end and your input has dots after the last `/`? Try `%r{([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*)/[^.]+\.[^.]+\z}`, but some more explanation of the requirements would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but I found the answer, just posting it.

Comment: What makes a file *hidden*?

Comment: @ClasG In UNIX machines, a file/directory name beginning with `.` is termed as hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regex = %r{([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*)\/[^.]}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are currently looking for `\/[^.]+$`, that is a `/` followed by any character except `.` until the end. Since the filename+extension format has a `.` character, it fails to match the second case.

Instead of using `[^.]+$`, check only that the character following `/` is not `.`, and match everything after that:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*)\/[^.].*$
```

Answer (score 2):

While there are some suggestions here that work, my suggestion would be

```
\/[^.][^\/\n]+$
```

It finds a *slash*, followed by anything but a dot, which in turn is followed by one, or more, of anything but a *slash* or a `newline`.

To handle the two lines given as an example,

```
Folder_1/.file
Folder/file.png
```

it takes **8** steps.

The suggested ones all work, but `([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*)\/[^.]` takes **75** steps, `([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*)\/[^.]+\.[^.]+\z` **78** steps and `([a-zA-Z0-9_ -]*)\/[^.].*$` takes **77** steps.

This may be totally irrelevant and I may have missed some angle, but I wanted to mention it ;)

[Se it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qK7zI7/1).